# Why is routing not working on my Dell N2048 switch

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, dell

I am in the process of replacing some older Dell Powerconnect switches with a some Dell N2048 switches. While doing this I wanted to go ahead and segregate certain areas of my network using VLANs. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

VLAN1: default, not used
VLAN10: network devices (printers, servers, etc)
VLAN20: Sales workstations
VLAN30: Support workstations

etc

I have routing enabled on each of the VLAN interfaces.

Right now I have the VLANs setup and I have the required ports set to 'Access' mode and 'untagged' with the PVID set to the appropriate VLAN.

The global gateway is set to the IP of the router. (I tried setting to the interface of the VLAN that has the network devices but it did not accept that IP)

On VLAN10 I have a port that goes to my firewall / router (Watchguard M300).

With this setup I'm able to reach other workstations in the same VLAN and anybody on VLAN10 is able to reach out to the internet. Other VLANs cannot get to the internet and cannot reach other VLANs.

If I set the router up with routes between the VLANs, I can then communicate across the VLANs with no issue and everyone can get to the internet. But, that is not what I want. I want the routing to be handled in the switch itself.

So my question is, what am I missing that is preventing inter-VLAN routing from taking place in the switch itself? I'm assuming I'm just missing something simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I've read through the quick-start guide, through the user guide, and watched several Dell youtube videos but I'm not finding anything that helps me out.

-- 
Some additional setup information:

The router is on VLAN10 (router ip 192.168.10.25, switchport 1/0/1). It (router) is configured with an external interface for the internet and a single internal trusted interface that connects to the switch. Right now it has two routes defined: one points to VLAN10 and one points to VLAN20. The gateway for both of those routes is the IP for the VLAN10 interface (192.168.10.16).

> console#show vlan
>
> VLAN   Name                             Ports          Type
>   -----  ---------------                  -------------  --------------
>   1      default                          Po1-128,       Default
>                                          Gi1/0/1,
>                                          Gi1/0/4-48,
>                                          Te1/0/1-2
>   10     Corporate                        Gi1/0/2        Static
>   20     Network and DevOps               Gi1/0/3        Static
>
> console>show ip interface
>   Default Gateway................................ 192.168.10.25
>   L3 MAC Address................................. F48E.380A.9AB8
>
> Routing Interfaces:
>
> Interface    State   IP Address      IP Mask         Method
>   ----------   -----   --------------- --------------- -------
>   Vl1          Down    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         DHCP
>   Vl10         Up      192.168.10.16   255.255.255.0   Manual
>   Vl20         Up      192.168.11.1    255.255.255.0   Manual
>
> console>show dot1x
>
> Administrative Mode............... Disabled
>   Dynamic VLAN Creation Mode........ Disabled
>   VLAN Assignment Mode.............. Disabled
>   Monitor Mode...................... Disabled
>   EAPOL Flood Mode.................. Disabled
>
> Port      Admin Mode         Oper Mode               Reauth   Reauth
>                                                        Control  Period
>   --------- ------------------ ----------------------- -------- ----------
>   Gi1/0/1   auto               N/A                     FALSE    3600
>   Gi1/0/2   auto               Authorized              FALSE    3600
>   Gi1/0/3   auto               Authorized              FALSE    3600
>
> console#show ip route
>
> Route Codes: R - RIP Derived, O - OSPF Derived, C - Connected, S - Static
>          B - BGP Derived, E - Externally Derived, IA - OSPF Inter Area
>          E1 - OSPF External Type 1, E2 - OSPF External Type 2
>          N1 - OSPF NSSA External Type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA External Type 2
>          S U - Unnumbered Peer, L - Leaked Route
>
> - Indicates the best (lowest metric) route for the subnet.
>
> No default gateway is configured. {NOTE: THIS WAS 192.168.10.25. Removed it to see if that would have any impact.}
>   C      *192.168.10.0/24 [0/1] directly connected,   Vl10
>   C      *192.168.11.0/24 [0/1] directly connected,   Vl20
>
> console#show ip vlan
>
> MAC Address used by Routing VLANs:   F48E.380A.9AB8
>
> ```
>        Logical
> ```
>
> VLAN ID   Interface        IP Address       Subnet Mask
>   -------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------
>   1        Vl1             0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0
>   10       Vl10            192.168.10.16    255.255.255.0
>   20       Vl20            192.168.11.1     255.255.255.0
>
> console#show ip brief
>
> Default Time to Live........................... 64
>   Routing Mode................................... Enabled
>   ICMP Rate Limit Interval....................... 1000 msec
>   ICMP Rate Limit Burst Size..................... 100 messages
>   ICMP Echo Replies.............................. Enabled
>   ICMP Redirect Mode............................. Enabled
>   Maximum Next Hops.............................. 1

Comment: It's not clear how you have things set up.  Where is the "router" connected, and how it configured?   Can you include the switch configuration?  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: I added some of the config settings. If I missed something that might help just let me know. The current setup may be totally screwed up since I've been testing various changes. At this point I might be better off just reloading the switch and starting from scratch.

Comment: For devices on VLAN 20, is the default gateway set to 192.168.11.1?

Comment: That's correct. VL10 devices point to 192.168.10.16 and VL20 devices point to 192.168.11.1 for their default gateways.

Actually.. i take that back... my VL10 device was using 192.168.10.25 as the default gateway. I changed it to the IP of the VLAN interface, 192.168.10.16, and now it cannot reach out to the internet.

Comment: And just to verify I'm reading this right:  a host on VL 20 cannot ping a host on VL 10?  Can you ping the VL 10 interface?

Comment: Right now devices on VLAN10 can ping devices on VLAN20 and vice-versa. Neither can reach the internet (I assume that's because I removed the global default gateway). This works as long as the router is connected. If I take the router off the network and try to let the switch handle the inter-vlan routing, no device can reach devices on any other vlan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40663/discussion-between-ron-trunk-and-michael-haynes).

Comment: It looks like I just had an incorrect default gateway on my end device. At this point it appears I'm working without the router in the loop. Thanks for taking the time to assist Ron and for providing some suggestions on what to do now.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the Dell N2000 series, IP routing is disabled by default and needs to be enabled.

Try adding `ip routing` or `routing` via the configuration command line as several major Ethernet switching manufacturers, including Cisco, have ip routing disabled by default.

Comment: You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.

Comment: @YLearn It's a common mistake / gotcha.  Cisco switches do not route between VLANs by default, even if you configure interface VLAN1 and interface VLAN2 both with IP addresses in unique subnets, the (layer 3) switch will not route between them.  Type "ip routing" from config mode and it works.  This is a valuable answer.  There are resident trolls here that downvote ad hominem. As a moderator, you should do something about it.

Comment: Your comment is a better answer than your answer. Yes, many of us are aware this is a common problem and we have had several such questions here. Let me put it this way, your answer is more like giving the OP a fish rather than teaching him to fish. Your comment does a much better job of explaining what is going on and how they OP can resolve the problem.

Comment: My original post mentions that I had routing configured (the manual actually tells you that it is disabled by default so that was never an issue). While your answer didn't do me any good it is a valid item to look at for those who don't read the manual or who may have glanced over it. My issue was that during testing I had changed the gateway on one device and that gimped up everything. Once I fixed that (thanks to Ron Trunk chatting with me and verifying the basic settings again) I was good to go. Was a reminder to always check the simple stuff and recheck everything as you test changes.

Comment: Your original post did not say you had routing enabled globally.  The 'global gateway is set to the IP of the router' indicates you are not a networking professional as what you mentioned is referred to as a default route, which may only affect management traffic, depending.  In any case, I'm glad you got it working.  Hire the professionals next time, also buy Cisco.  You'll save money and get better results.